# Snowflake does not load the data for Cadilla - Ç character as delimiter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to load the data into sample table with below ddl

```
create or replace table sample1(id varchar(1000), name varchar(200), city varchar(20));
```

File content

```
'1'Ç'aaa'Ç'a'
'2'Ç'bbb'Ç'b'
```

Doing manual load from UI

I have used the Ç and \u00c7 as delimiter, but I am getting the following error:

Error on line 2, character 1, column 1 ("ID")
Number of columns in file (1) does not match that of the corresponding table (3), use file format option error_on_column_count_mismatch=false to ignore this error

Another delimiter, like @, works fine.

Comment: Since this is a multibyte character have you used a hex value for it as in our [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table)? So try `FIELD_DELIMITER = '\xC3\x87'` and let me know if it works.

Comment: Same error, below is the copy command

`
COPY INTO "TEST"."TEST"."SAMPLE1"
FROM '@"TEST"."TEST"."%SAMPLE1"/__snowflake_temp_import_files__/'
FILES = ('file.txt')
FILE_FORMAT = (
    TYPE=CSV,
    SKIP_HEADER=0,
    FIELD_DELIMITER = '\xC3\x87',
    ENCODING='ISO88591',
    TRIM_SPACE=FALSE,
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY=NONE,
    DATE_FORMAT=AUTO,
    TIME_FORMAT=AUTO,
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT=AUTO
)
ON_ERROR=ABORT_STATEMENT
PURGE=TRUE

`

Comment: That's because your text file `file.txt` is most probably `UTF-8` and not `ISO88591`. Replace `ENCODING='ISO88591'` with `ENCODING='UTF-8'` and it should work, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a multibyte character you need to use a hex value for it as in our [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table):

```
Multibyte characters

    Hex values (prefixed by \x). For example, for records delimited by the cent (¢) character, specify the hex (\xC2\xA2) value.
```

Setting the `FIELD_DELIMITER = '\xC3\x87'` along with `ENCODING='UTF-8'` would allow the COPY INTO to load the data successfully.